# Complete the rest of this seasonal sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, seasonal

Usually I don't like this kind of "guess the next terms" puzzle.
But at this time of the year I wonder whether it makes sense to post such a question.

So here is the start of a sequence:
$$33, 3, 33, 3, 35, 12, 3, 0, 44, 4, 43, 3, 32, \dots$$
The task is to complete the sequence.
Moreover, it is optional but preferable that you add some additional message together with your answer.

Note on the source: the sequence is definitely not created by me, but the puzzle is my creation (as long as it hasn't been coincidentally posted before).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's provide the next 3 terms to bring this sequence to a pleasing place to pause:

> 33, 3, 33, 3, 35, 12, 3, 0, 44, 4, 43, 3, 32, **23, 2, 5**

If you're wondering what's going on here, perhaps it might help to replace these numbers with letters, like so:

> EE, E, EE, E, EG, CD, E, x, FF, F, FE, E, ED, **DE, D, G**

Since this corresponds to...

> ...the main **musical notes** required to play the chorus line of the festive classic *[Jingle Bells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CWJNqyub3o)*! In fact, if you wish to play the tune on a piano using just the right hand the numbers here could represent the **fingers** used to play it, numbering the thumb as '1', through to the pinky as '5'. (NB The '0' and the equivalent 'x' represent a rest where no note is played.)
>
> ```
>  3  3   | 3     | 3  3   | 3     | 3  5   | 1   2   | 3   | 0      |
>  E  E   | E     | E  E   | E     | E  G   | C   D   | E   | x      |
>  Jingle | bells | Jingle | bells | Jingle | all the | way | (rest) |
>
>
>  4  4    | 4    | 4     3  | 3         | 3   2     | 2 3   | 2      | 5    |
>  F  F    | F    | F (F) E  | E   (E)(E)| E   D     | D E   | D      | G    |
>  Oh what | fun  | It is to | ride in a | one horse | o-pen | sleigh | HEY! |
> ```

As for an additional message...

> Well, this seems like a good opportunity to say:
>
>  *"Seasons greetings! Wishing you all a Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year!"*

Comment: Nice answer and thanks a lot for your additional message! ^_^